# Unity - Instantiate GameObject from client on Network

Tags: unity, c#, unity-networking

I am building a game where a weapon shoots `prefab` bullets. I am trying to make this a multiplayer game, so the bullets need to be spawned into the Network.

What happens right now is that if I shoot a bullet from a `host`, the bullet is shot, but doesn't appear on the `client` screen. If I shoot the bullet from the `client`, the bullet doesn't appear on either screen. In fact, the function `CmdShoot()` isn't even called, as the `Debug.Log("Hello")` is not called. Here is the current code:

```
public class Gun : MonoBehaviour
{

    private GameObject bulletPrefab;

    void Update()
    {
        if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0)) {
            owner.GetComponent<PlayerSetup>().CmdShoot(bulletPrefab, transform.position, owner.name, GetComponentInParent<Weapon>().angle);
        }
    }
}
```

```
public class PlayerSetup : NetworkBehaviour
{

    void Start ()
    {
        // Disable components if not local player
    }

    [Command]
    public void CmdShoot(GameObject bulletPrefab, Vector3 position, string playerName, float angle)
    {
        Debug.Log("Hello");
        GameObject bullet = Instantiate(bulletPrefab, position, Quaternion.identity);
        bullet.name = "bullet: " + playerName;
        bullet.GetComponent<Rigidbody>().AddForce(Quaternion.AngleAxis(angle, Vector3.forward) * Vector3.right * bulletPrefab.GetComponent<Bullet>().force);
        Destroy(bullet, 10f);
        NetworkServer.Spawn(bullet);
    }
}
```

**Edit:**

This piece of code doesn't work either, gives the same result. No error, but the function is also not called. The Input is detected though:

````
    void Update() {
        if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0)) {
            CmdShoot();
        }
    }

    [Command]
    void CmdShoot()
    {
        Debug.Log("Shoot");
        GameObject bullet = Instantiate(gunComponent.bulletPrefab, gun.position, Quaternion.identity);
        bullet.name = "bullet: " + transform.name;
        bullet.GetComponent<Rigidbody>().AddForce(Quaternion.AngleAxis(GetComponentInChildren<Weapon>().angle, Vector3.forward) * Vector3.right * gunComponent.bulletPrefab.GetComponent<Bullet>().force);
        Destroy(bullet, 10f);
        NetworkServer.Spawn(bullet);
    }

```
````

Answer (score 1):

First things first. You should inherit from the proper base class. **NetworkBehavior** is the way to go.

Then there are conditions that your prefab should meet before getting passed to the method. According to documentation the GameObject should have a **NetworkIdentity** attached in order to be transmitted. The complete list of argument restrictions can be found [here](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Networking.CommandAttribute.html).

There is also one more catch. The **CommandAttribute** can be used for Players invoking the method on Server side from Client side only. I think the intended usage is input syncing rather than a RPC-like behaviour.

For Server to client transmission use the [ClientRpcs](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/UNetActions.html).

Hope this pushes you in the right direction. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

You want to make sure it is the localplayer shooting, and if not then just remove and/or return out of Update()

```
void Update() {
if(!isLocalPlayer){Destroy(gameObject); return; }
    if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0)) {
        CmdShoot();
    }
}
```